# Optimizing MySQL table for faster ORDER BY performance

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with this schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE `data_realtime` (
     `id` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `timestamp` int(10) NOT NULL,
     `ticker_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `price` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `volume` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `bid` decimal(7,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
     `bid_sz` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
     `ask` decimal(7,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
     `ask_sz` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `ticker_timestamp` (`ticker_id`,`timestamp`) USING BTREE,
     CONSTRAINT `data_realtime_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ticker_id`) REFERENCES `tickers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11330043 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I'm trying to run a simple query to order the data by the timestamp:

```
select * from data_realtime ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

This takes 2.5s (for ~4.5M rows, which will increase to about 12M rows eventually). But if I simply run

```
select * from data_realtime
```

it takes .25 s

I have a composite index on timestamp (with ticker_id) which I thought would help tackle this problem.

What can I do to improve performance when ordering?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:
To add to the original problem I have this query:

```
SELECT data_latest.*, data_1m.timestamp timestamp_1m, data_1m.price price_1m, data_1m.volume volume_1m FROM 
    (SELECT B.* FROM 
        (SELECT ticker_id, max(timestamp) max_timestamp FROM `data_rt` GROUP BY ticker_id) 
    A 
    LEFT JOIN 
    data_rt B 
    ON 
    A.ticker_id=B.ticker_id 
    and A.max_timestamp=B.timestamp) 
data_latest 
LEFT JOIN 
data_rt data_1m 
ON 
data_latest.timestamp <= (data_1m.timestamp + (60*1) ) 
AND data_latest.timestamp > (data_1m.timestamp + 60*(1-0.5)) 
AND data_latest.timestamp>data_1m.timestamp 
AND data_latest.ticker_id=data_1m.ticker_id 
ORDER BY data_1m.timestamp ASC
```

On a set of 1M rows it takes about 1.3s. Adding the last ORDER BY is what increases the time drastically. If I instead ORDER BY timestamp it takes only 0.05s.

What can I do improve when sorting using a temp column?

Comment: What order is the composite index in? (timestamp, ticker_id) should help; (ticker_id, timestamp) won't.

Comment: Yes it is (ticker_id,timestamp). Why does the order of indexing matter?

Comment: The order is the order it is sorted; in such an index MySQL would have to traverse every ticket_id, checking the timestamp field values under each. Since whether this would help is VERY data dependent, the decided behavior is to ignore such indexes. _(Data dependent as in: if every ticket id has a different timestamp, it is very costly; but could be helpful if there were relatively few ticket_id values, each with numerous timestamp values.)_

Comment: That makes sense. And it worked. The query now runs just as fast as it did without sorting. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing can help speed up queries; but only when the indexes are ones that MySQL will take advantage of. Composite indexes such as an index on (`a`, `b`) will help in queries involving `a` and `b` together; such as ones with `WHERE a = N AND b = M` or `ORDER BY a, b`. Such an index will even help on queries involving just `a`. Basically, any composite index `(a, b, .... n)` also acts as the indexes `(a, b, .... n-1)`, `(a, b, .... n-2)`, ... `(a, b)`, and `(a)`.

However, do to their applicability varying widely depending on actual data values (*see my second comment on question itself*); they cannot be used for the latter fields in the index when the earlier ones are not also involved. I.E. `(a, b)` is not used when queries just involve `b`. _`(a,b,c, ...,n)` can and often will be used for queries involving `(a,b,n)` but will only function as effectively as an `(a,b)` index.

Comment: Slightly drifting from the original question but, if I wanted to order by a temp column how would do I use indexing in that case? The temp column is derived from the timestamp column itself, but ordering on it is slower than order by the original timestamp column.

Comment: I added a subquestion to the original question with details about the problem.

Comment: The ON conditions seem a bit strange to me, and at first glance leave me wondering if you get any results for the data_1m; but the usual way I use if I really need performance from a query with a subquery like that is to dump the subquery results into an indexed temp table in a preliminary query, and then join to the temp table instead.